# run selenium without opening a browser in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, tags, cucumber, bdd

I have a question about using selenium in cucumber.

here is the cucumber features:

```
@selenium @javascript
  Scenario: Create forum
    Given I have a site named "hairclub" and I logged in as admin
    When I am on the "admin" page
```

To run, I use this command:

```
cucumber features/forum.feature
```

It works fine; it opens the browser (as you can see `@selenium @javascript tag`). Everything looks good.

I want to run the same cucumber script but not open the browser; I imagine if the scenario grows it will take a while to run with the browser. I want both the capability to run with browser open and also without browser opening. Is there any command I can pass it from terminal to overwrite `@selenium @javascript`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't run Selenium without a browser, because Selenium works by controlling the browser.

However, you can run Cucumber features without using Selenium.

If the scenario doesn't require JavaScript then you can use mechanize:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :mechanize
```

If you do need to test JavaScript, then Thoughtbot have just released this helpful gem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit